# jQuery .addClass applying to everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a like button that uses jQuery. The like button works as expected however due to the way I have it setup it changes every icon on the page to a heart

code:

```
if (data.liked) {
    updateText(this_, data.likescount, "")
    $(".like-btn").prepend("<i></i>");
    $("i").addClass("fa fa-heart-o liked-heart");  //problem line
} else {
    updateText(this_, data.likescount, "")
    $(".like-btn").prepend("<i></i>");
    $("i").addClass("fa fa-heart-o unliked-heart"); //problem line
```

From what i userstand the issue is that I am appending the class `fa fa-heart-o ...` to all `i` elements. How can I just apply it to the like button

full code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         function updateText(btn, newCount, verb){
         btn.text(newCount + " " + verb)
     }

     $(".like-btn").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       var this_ = $(this)
       var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
       var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes")) | 0
       var addLike = likeCount + 1
       var removeLike = likeCount - 1
       if (likeUrl){
          $.ajax({
           url: likeUrl,
           method: "GET",
           data: {},
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data)
             var newLikes;
             if (data.liked){
                  updateText(this_, data.likescount, "")
                  $(".like-btn").prepend("<i></i>");
                  $( "i" ).addClass( "fa fa-heart-o liked-heart" );
              } else {
                  updateText(this_, data.likescount, "")
                  $(".like-btn").prepend("<i></i>");   
                  $( "i" ).addClass( "fa fa-heart-o unliked-heart" );    

              }
           }, error: function(error){
             console.log(error)
             console.log("error")
           }
         })
       }       
     })
 })
</script> 

<a class="like-btn" data-href='{{ post.get_api_like_url }}' data-likes="{{ post.likes.count }}" href="{{ post.get_like_url }}"><i class="{% if userliked %}fa fa-heart-o liked-heart{% else %}fa fa-heart-o unliked-heart{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ post.likes.count }}</a>
```

Update: got both working individually the icon update and text update. However when I put them together when I click the like button it updates the like number but deletes the icon

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            function updateText(btn, newCount, verb){
            btn.text(newCount + " " + verb)
        }

    $(".like-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let this_ = $(this)
    var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
    var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes")) | 0
    var addLike = likeCount + 1
    var removeLike = likeCount - 1
    if (likeUrl){
          $.ajax({
           url: likeUrl,
           method: "GET",
           data: {},
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data)
             var newLikes;
                 let is_liked = this_.find('i').hasClass('fa-heart');
                 if (is_liked){
                  this_.find('i').removeClass('fa-heart').addClass('fa-heart-o');
                  updateText(this_, data.likescount, "")
                  
              } else {
                  this_.find('i').removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');
                  updateText(this_, data.likescount, "")
              }
           }, error: function(error){
             console.log(error)
             console.log("error")
           }
         })
       }       
     })
 })
    
</script>
```

final working code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            function updateText(btn, newCount, verb){
            btn.text(newCount + " " + verb)
        }

    $(".like-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let this_ = $(this)
    var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
    var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes")) | 0
    var addLike = likeCount + 1
    var removeLike = likeCount - 1
    
    if (likeUrl){
          $.ajax({
           url: likeUrl,
           method: "GET",
           data: {},
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data)
             var newLikes;
                 let is_liked = this_.find('i').hasClass('fa fa-heart liked-heart');
                 let cur_likes = +this_.find('span').text()
                 if (is_liked){
                    this_.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-heart liked-heart').addClass('fa fa-heart-o unliked-heart');
                        this_.find('span').text(cur_likes-1);
                  
              } else {
                this_.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-heart-o unliked-heart').addClass('fa fa-heart liked-heart');
                    this_.find('span').text(cur_likes+1);
              }
           }, error: function(error){
             console.log(error)
             console.log("error")
           }
         })
       }       
     })
 })
            <a class="like-btn" data-href='{{ post.get_api_like_url }}' data-likes="{{ post.likes.count }}" href="{{ post.get_like_url }}"><i class="{% if userliked %}fa fa-heart liked-heart{% else %}fa fa-heart-o unliked-heart{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>{{ post.likes.count }}</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently targeting every '.like-btn' on the page and also targeting every `<i>`. As mentioned in the other answer, you can use jQuery's [.find(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the existing `<i>` tag (rather than prepend it) and simplify your code a bit with a `removeClass/addClass` combo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".like-btn").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let this_ = $(this)
      let is_liked = this_.find('i').hasClass('fa-heart');
      let cur_likes = +this_.find('span').text()
      if (is_liked) {
        this_.find('i').removeClass('fa-heart').addClass('fa-heart-o');
        this_.find('span').text(cur_likes-1);
      } else {
        this_.find('i').removeClass('fa-heart-o').addClass('fa-heart');
          this_.find('span').text(cur_likes+1);
   }
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<a class="like-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o "></i> <span>5</span></a>
<a class="like-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> <span>9</span></a>
<a class="like-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> <span>12</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got both working individually the icon update and text update. However when I put them together when i click the like button it updates the like number but deletes the icon. Could you take a look at the new code snippet. Thanks again

Comment: I modified the html a little to set that number apart in a `<span>` tag and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `.like-btn`, it contains `i` tag, why do you try again `$(".like-btn").prepend("<i></i>");` in the `success` ? Since you have stored `$(this)` in the `this_` variable you can easily get the target `i` by `this_.find('i')` and in the success method and then try to add or remove class from the selected `i`.